# Styles not working on Mac but correct on Windows

Tags: html, css, windows, macos

I have a search bar that works perfectly on Windows but not macs, we have had 3 different people try it out and they have reported back saying that the search bar is not in the right place

Here is how it should look: http://puu.sh/fxTdJ/a19ae11d62.jpg

And here are the styles:

```
#search {
    position:relative;
    top:-30px;
}
#search div {
    padding-right:0;
}
#search button {
    height:33px;
    margin-top:1px;
    background:#666;
    color:#ccc;
    border:1px solid #666;
    border-radius:3px;

}
```

Here is the URL
http://178.62.26.90/essentialweddinghire/public/home

Comment: Looks issue with SAFARI brower. not specific to mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try giving `clear:both` to `#search` in your css:

```
#search {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
}
```

Comment: @ben shepherd : you applied the same and updated or server very fast :D ... now it as answer at least :P

Comment: plus 1 for proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do more Just Remove `padding-left: 0;` of `.nav` from your code

```
.nav {
 padding-left: 0;
}
```

This issue looks in mozilla also Here. 
I think this will help you. Also above answer is correct. Given by Era